# Excel switch 2 cells around depending on value

Tags: excel, if-statement, switch-statement

I am new to excel and was wondering if you could help with an issue i am trying to figure out.

I have 3 columns and would like to switch A1 with B1 if the date dd/mm/yy in B1 is before the date in A1.

Comment: Would if be an issue if you put the results in other columns, then copy paste those over columns A and B?

Comment: The file has many errors (2k plus) So i was hoping to create some kind of formula that would switch them around

Comment: The problem is that formula don't change the value of cells they are not typed in. If you put a formula in C1, it will never change cell A1 no matter what you do. And if you put a formula in A1, you lose the original content of A1. And I work with some 800k of data in my excel files, and such formulas were never a problem. If you are okay with that (putting the results in temporary columns), I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let's say that columns D and E are empty. You will put the formula in those columns. In column D will be the dates which should go to column A and in column E will be those to go in column B.

In cell D1, put the formula:

```
=IF(B1 < A1, B1, A1)
```

In cell E1, put the formula:

```
=IF(B1 < A1, A1, B1)
```

And copy the formula down.

> Sidenote: To make things go a bit quicker, you can select both cells D1 and E1 (selecting D1 first), go to the bottom of the spreasheet using the scroll bar only push and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click the cell E in the last row. This should select everything from above till that cell you clicked. Then release <kbd>Shift</kbd> and push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to replicate the formulae throughout the selected columns.

After having the all formulae, copy and paste as values in place (To paste as values, you right click and go to Paste Special, find 'Values' among the different options.

Copy again and paste onto columns A and B, then delete columns D and E.